# Angular 9 ngx bootstrap : modal opening bug

Tags: angular, modal-dialog, ngx-bootstrap

Hi everyone,

I encounter a problem to use modal in angular with ngx bootstrap.

My modal is in a separate component and i use a subject to send an event to Open it.

My problem :
When i click on the button to Open the modal, subject work (i log the event in console) but the modal does not appear.
The ngbmodal div with modal content is in the DOM page => the js is load correctly apparently.

which is strange, when i navigate to another page, the modal appear like magic......

Can you help me please :)

Modal component html :

```html
<ng-template #add_file let-c="close" let-d="dismiss">
  <div class="modal-body p-0">
    <a class="closeBtn" (click)="d('Cross click')">
      <img src="../../assets/images/icones/picto/closePopup.png"/>
    </a>
    <h2>{{ 'ad.add.file' | translate }}</h2>
  </div>
  <div>
    <form [formGroup]="addPostForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(addPostForm.value)">
      <app-file-upload formControlName="file" [progress]="progress" [type]="mediaType"></app-file-upload>
      <button class="button" type="submit">{{ 'ad.add.file.submit' | translate }}</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

Modal component ts :

```
  @Input() modalAddFileSubject: Subject<any>;
  @Output() pictureAddEvent = new EventEmitter();
  @ViewChild('add_file') modal: TemplateRef<any>;
  private subscriptions: Subscription;
  mediaType: MediaType;
  private downloadURL: string;
  addPostForm;
  progress;
  private modalRef: NgbModalRef;

  constructor(private modalService: NgbModal,
              private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.subscriptions = new Subscription();
    this.initializeModal();
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.subscriptions.unsubscribe();
  }

  initializeModal() {
    this.subscriptions.add(this.modalAddFileSubject.subscribe(type => {
      console.log('Ajout post of type : ', type);
      this.mediaType = type;
      this.addPostForm = this.formBuilder.group({
        file: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
      });
      this.modalRef = this.modalService.open(this.modal);
    }));
  }

  handleFileInput(event) {
    console.log(event.target.files);
  }

  onSubmit(postData) {
    this.pictureAddEvent.emit(postData);
    this.modalRef.close();
  }
```

Parent component with modal open subject :

```
  addPicture() {
    this.modalAddFileSubject.next('image');
  }
```

Thank you.

Comment: Could you add the modal service and parent component html? Also if possible can you recreate this example in stackblitz

Comment: Is there any styling conflict maybe?

Comment: thank you for your response. I found a solution, see below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i find the solution. I use the ngx bootstrap in wrong way.

I simply use :

```
this.modalRef = this.modalService.show(FileAdComponent);
```

And i remove modal template reference into parent component template :

```
<app-file-ad [modalAddFileSubject]="modalAddFileSubject (pictureAddEvent)="addPictureAd($event)"></app-file-ad>
```

Thank you very much.